# Remove soap water mixed with granulated sugar

Tags: sugar, cleaning

Due to the lockdown amidst COVID-19, I bought [**granulated sugar**](https://www.google.com/search?q=granulated%20sugar) online and got it delivered.

[image]

To take extra precaution, I washed the sealed packet with soap water.

Later I found out that the packet had some small holes and the sugar inside is now mixed with soapy water.

Is there any **home-remedy** using which I can refine/purify/clean the sugar and remove the soap water out or would I have to just throw the entire packet of sugar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As sugar dissolves extremely readily when damp, let alone wet, you could just manually pick out the clumps.

If it's not clumped, it didn't get wet. Soap itself wouldn't travel any further than the water through the sugar, but the smell may. If the soap was perfumed, just getting the clumps out may not be sufficient. If you can still smell it afterwards, just throw the whole lot out.

I'd consider sugar & soap to be equally soluble in water [for these purposes] & therefore no home remedy will separate the two once they're mixed. There's no rescue for the clumped parts, only that which remained dry.